# VHDL Traffic Light

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Traffic_Light is

Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
       input : in  STD_LOGIC;
       output : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0));

end Traffic_Light;

architecture Behavioral of Traffic_Light is

type state_type is (S0,S1,S2);  --type of state machine.
signal present_state, next_state: state_type;  --current and next state declaration.



begin

process 
begin
    wait until clk'event and clk = '0';
    present_state <= next_state;
end process;


process (clk,reset)
begin
    if (reset='1') then
        current_state <= S0;  --default state on reset.
    end if;
end process;


process (present_state, input)
begin

    case present_state is
        when S0 =>                  --when current state is s0
        if(input = '0') then
            output <= "10";
            next_state <= S1;
        else
            output <= "00";
            next_state <= S2;
        end if;


        when S1 =>                  --when current state is s1
        if(input = '0') then
            output <= "01";
            next_state <= S0;
        else
            output <= "00";
            next_state <= S2;
        end if;


        when S2 =>                  --when current state is s2
        if(input = '0') then
            output <= "01";
            next_state <= S0;
        else
            output <= "11";
            next_state <= S2;
        end if;


    end case;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I cant seem to get every state change to occur only at the falling edge of the clock.

The simulation does not show the various changes in the `present state`, it just shows `S0` all the way through.

All the state changes have been entered correctly. It just requires the synchronous reset an state changes to occur at the falling edge.

Comment: Your sample code shouldn't analyze, there is no declaration for `current_state`.

Comment: Obviously, you didn't even try to compile this. Please post accurate questions and show that you reasonably tried to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First replace `current_state` with `present_state`. Then you can't drive `present_state` from two processes since it's not a resolved type. You have to do something like

```
process (clk,reset)
begin
  if (reset='1') then
    present_state <= S0;  --default state on reset.
  elsif clk'event and clk = '0' then
    present_state <= next_state;  
  end if;
end process;
```